# Smooth Scrolling Div on Hover

Tags: jquery, hover, slider, gallery, smoothing

I'm having a great deal of trouble figuring out how to make this div continuously scroll smoothly while hovered over the arrows. It's almost like there is easing on the animation but I don't have any easing set for this instance of the animation. I'm really at a loss as to how to make this smoother. Any suggestions??

http://dev.infomedia.net/carousel/

JS Found here: http://dev.infomedia.net/carousel/bcarousel.js

The hover animation doesn't even use the easing option (line 150).  And it also sets the optino value to '' when the event is "hover" (line 30). I also have gone as far as commenting out EVERY reference to easing in this script: Line 19, 154, 161
I also commented out the reference to the jquery.easing plugin completely, but it still seems to be easing. It's driving me crazy.

I changed the event to "click" and then clicked the right arrow really fast, and that is the effect I want for the hover event. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: +1 on the question, I was just looking for how to do this.... downloading code sample! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting speed to 6, interval to 1, and easing to ''.

It works quite smooth.

K

Comment: Wow. that worked great! Thanks. I can't believe i struggled with that for so long....